# jQuery Limit number of ticked Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, serialization, checkbox

**UPDATE SOLVED**: Should be **`name = 'q1[]'`**

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=q1]).click(function() {

    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=q1]:checked").length >= 7;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=q1]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
});
```

I'm coming unstuck however, the need to `serialize` the results when saving means I have to have `name` set to `name=q1[]` in the PHP code and at this point, the above jQuery to limit the number of checked checkboxes stops working.

I've tried adding in `name=q1[]' but the code simply stops working!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `[name='q1[]']` or `[name=q1\\[\\]]`?

Comment: Oh heck - I'm embarrassed!!!!  How did I not spot that.  Frederic, answer the question and I'll mark as such!!!  Thanks and apologies for such a simple question!

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/mGeHj/

Comment: @Tushar thanks but that's not the issue, Frederic has answered it - I completely missed the apostrophes!